# get_posts not returning all posts

Tags: wordpress

I have to mount the blog posts manually, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to work, It only brings 9 pages, with 4 posts each, but the blog has 83 posts!

```
<?php
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'       => 4,
        'offset'            => $paged*4,
        'orderby'           => 'post_date',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters'  => true
    );
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
?>
```

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Double check all your 83 posts are "published".

Comment: yes they are all published, but I noticed that it brings only posts with 'no category' , how may I get all posts including other categories?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Problem is your 'numberposts' is set to 4
Put it at -1 to get all posts:

```
 'numberposts'       => -1,
```

If you don't set numberposts here, WordPress will pull the number of posts from your Dashboard settings (under Settings -> Reading)

Comment: man ... you save my day .. thanks.. by the way i don't set numberposts .. but it has default value from WP so i set it to -1 to force WP get it

Answer (score 5):

The below note is from this [codex section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

> Note: With use of the offset, the above query should be used only on a
>   category that has more than one post in it, otherwise there'll be no
>   output.

So in-order to display all posts, there should be at-least 2 posts in each categories.

You can try [**Loops**](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) to get all posts. Check [The Loop in Action](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action) also.