# Auto-update posts in Wordpress with Magic Fields

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Im trying to update all my posts at once on Wordpress, instead of painfully going on each page and Updating it.
I made a small plugin using the wp_update_post, but it didnt recognize and update the Magic Fields postmeta. I then tried to include SaveCustomFields from the RCCWP_POST from Magic Fields, however it requires $_POST information to work.
I am open to any suggestion, i tried a few SQL queries to accomplish this with no success.

It would look like that:

```
function activate()
{
    $my_posts = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'post', 'numberposts' => -1 ) );
    foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post )
    {
        wp_update_post( $my_post );
        RCCWP_Post::SaveCustomFields($my_post->ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: numberposts is set as -1, im pretty sure that has to be a positive number.

Comment: Actually -1 allows you to get every post instead of setting an extremely high number to catch them all - cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010497/get-posts-not-returning-all-posts

Comment: Makes sense. Now what exactly are you modifying on the posts themselves? In your code you are fetching the posts and resaving the same info?

"Before calling wp_update_post() it is necessary to create an array to pass the necessary elements" It seems you should be sending an array with whatever you are trying to update.  

$my_post = array(
      'ID'           => 37,
      'post_content' => 'This is the updated content.')

Comment: When you create a new category of Field in the Magic Fields plugin, those are not added to older posts automatically - at leats with the version I use. Therefore, i just need to update it without touching anything and the new fields will appear in the database. I just solved my issue going through a number of SQL queries, a rather inefficient solution but that will do.

Comment: Put your solution as an answer so if other stumble upon this question they have something to help them. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually updated the field needed in the database:

INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT post_id, "new_criteria", meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE meta_key="old_criteria" AND meta_value!="";